# Swapping an image when a toggle has been clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have the following code where I added a plus symbol to one of my service titles. I was informed by someone that when that service is clicked on I should have a minus sign take its place to show that it can be minimized. I am unsure of how to swap out the plus sign when the description has been expanded. Does anyone have any ideas of how I could do that?

Here is a snippet. Click on one of the service names to see the description expand.

```js
$('.service_wrapper').click(function() {
  var thisDescription = $('.service_description', $(this));

  // Hide all other descriptions
  $('.service_description').not(thisDescription).hide();

  // Toggle (show or hide) this description
  thisDescription.slideToggle(500);
});
```

```css
.service_wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 20%;
}
.service_list {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.service_title {
  padding: 15px 12px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.service_title:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.service_description {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service_list">
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">
      <img src="http://realtorcatch.com/icons/plusSymbol.png" alt="Service" style="width:10px;height:10px;">Floors</div>
    <div class="service_description">The best floors!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Roofs</div>
    <div class="service_description">Your roof will be perfect!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Siding</div>
    <div class="service_description">mmmm siding.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Paint</div>
    <div class="service_description">Fabulous paint!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Kitchen Remodels</div>
    <div class="service_description">Pretty kitchen.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the plus sign? Where is the minus sign? Are they images?

Comment: Yes, the plus sign is an image. It is next to the first service name. I just didn't add them all in the snippet. The minus sign would be : img src="http://realtorcatch.com/icons/minusSymbol.png"

Comment: I would think simply changing the `src` attribute of the img element containing the plus image on click to the source of your minus image would provide the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Could you provide an example or link, I am unsure of what you mean.

Comment: It is really easy to do, but you need to change your script a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simply toggling a class to achieve this.

You can add the icon as a background image of a pseudo element inserted into the `.service_title` element. Then you can simply toggle a class in order to change the icon. Update the background image URLs accordingly. See the updated example for the modified jQuery; it's still only 5 lines.

The relevant CSS:

```
.service_title:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC7i2.png') 0 0 / 10px 10px no-repeat;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.closed .service_title:before {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma4L4.png');
}
```

#### Updated Example:

```js
$('.service_wrapper').click(function() {
  var thisDescription = $('.service_description', $(this));
  $('.service_description').not(thisDescription).hide().parent().removeClass('closed');
  thisDescription.slideToggle(500).parent().toggleClass('closed');
});
```

```css
.service_wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 20%;
}
.service_list {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
.service_title {
  padding: 15px 12px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.service_title:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC7i2.png') 0 0 / 10px 10px no-repeat;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.closed .service_title:before {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma4L4.png');
}
.service_title:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.service_description {
  display: none;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service_list">
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Floors</div>
    <div class="service_description">The best floors!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Roofs</div>
    <div class="service_description">Your roof will be perfect!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Siding</div>
    <div class="service_description">mmmm siding.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Paint</div>
    <div class="service_description">Fabulous paint!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="service_wrapper">
    <div class="service_title">Kitchen Remodels</div>
    <div class="service_description">Pretty kitchen.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works like 99% perfect. How can I add padding in between the plus sign and service title? I have had this issue before with a background image in a css file. I can't ever figure out how to add padding to the right side of the image.

Comment: You can just add padding to the pseudo element.. `.service_title:before { padding-right: 6px; }`..

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! So you are just toggling between classes to make the image change?

Comment: @Becky Yep. In this case, the `.closed` class is being toggled. It determines which background image is displayed.

Comment: What does the :Before css element do?

Comment: @Becky It's a pseudo element that places the image *before* the `.service_title` element. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working example, i change a little de html and Js

```
    $('.service_wrapper').click(function() {

          var thisDescription = $('.service_description', $(this));

        var t = $(this);
        if(t.hasClass('open'))
          {
            t.removeClass('open');
            t.find('.status').html("+");
          }else {
            t.addClass('open');
            t.find('.status').html("-");

          }

          // Hide all other descriptions
          $('.service_description').not(thisDescription).hide();

          // Toggle (show or hide) this description
          thisDescription.slideToggle(500);
        });
```

[the working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoNMMy)

Comment: My answer is more simple :'(

Answer (score 0):

You could just change it within your click binding...

Let's say your using images, just add a data-attribute you can query when you need to, like this...

HTML

```
<div class="service_wrapper">
    <img data-state="plus" class="state" src="plus.png" alt="More"/>
    <div class="service_title">Paint</div>
    <div class="service_description">Fabulous paint!</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.service_wrapper').click(function() {
    var state = $(this).find('.state');
    if(state.data('state') == 'plus')
        state.attr({ 'src': 'minus.png', 'alt': 'Less' }).data('state', 'minus');
    else
        state.attr({ 'src': 'plus.png', 'alt': 'More' }).data('state', 'plus');
});
```